# Routing in Flask when no function is given

Tags: python, flask

I was going through this website where no function has been given to the '/' route but it still opens the login page when not logged in, I'm not sure how exactly this routing works...
Link:
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/profile-application-using-python-flask-and-mysql/

Code:

```
@app.route('/')
@app.route('/login', methods =['GET', 'POST'])
def login():
    msg = ''
    if request.method == 'POST' and 'username' in request.form and 'password' in request.form:
        username = request.form['username']
        password = request.form['password']
        cursor = mysql.connection.cursor(MySQLdb.cursors.DictCursor)
        cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE username = % s AND password = % s', (username, password, ))
        account = cursor.fetchone()
        if account:
            session['loggedin'] = True
            session['id'] = account['id']
            session['username'] = account['username']
            msg = 'Logged in successfully !'
            return render_template('index.html', msg = msg)
        else:
            msg = 'Incorrect username / password !'
    return render_template('login.html', msg = msg)
```

Comment: Both of those decorators are for the login() function, and so both '/' and '/login' will route to login.html.

Answer (score 0):

Flask lets you [define routes in decorators](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/api/?highlight=route#flask.Flask.route). A given function may have one or more decorators.

Since the decorator for the `/` route is on the same function as the `login/` route, both routes are handled by the `login()` function.

Since it's kind of confusing to have both routes pointing to the same function, one suspects that the author of the tutorial is using the first decorator as a placeholder, and will eventually change the `/` route to point to a template for a "landing page". (There are lots of reasons to have multiple routes hitting the same function, but no others are apparent from the code).

You might have been better served had the author included a comment, or explicitly redirected `/`:

```
@route("/")
def placeholder():
    """Redirect root to ``login`` for now"""
    return redirect("/login")
```

Does this make sense?